# The Object Class and Its toString()

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

The superclass Student contains:
a constructor  that accepts a String  corresponding to the name  of the school the student attends
a toString method  that returns 'student at X' where X is the name  of the school the student attends.

Write a class  definition for the subclass HighSchoolStudent containing:
a constructor  accepting a String  which is used as a parameter  to the superclass constructor 
a toString method  that returns 'high school student at X'. This method  must use the toString method  of its superclass.

Instructor Notes: You are writing only the subclass. 
In it you will have a constructor (which has a parameter - a string) it will call the superclass's constructor passing in this parameter to it. 
It will also overwrite the tostring method by returning "high school" followed by what is returned in the superclass's toString method.

```
public class HighSchoolStudent extends Student
{
    public String HighSchoolStudent()
    {
        return "high school student at "+super.toString();
    }
}
HighSchoolStudent.java:1: error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
public class HighSchoolStudent extends Student
       ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
1 public class HighSchoolStudent extends Student
2 {
3   public String HighSchoolStudent()
4   {
5       return "high school student at "+super.toString();
6   }
7 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, the method which has the same name of the class, is the constructor,
so, it should be:

```
public HighSchoolStudent(String schoolName) {
    super(schoolName);
}
```

and the toString method should be:

```
public String toString() {
    return "high school " + super.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because the class is called `HighSchoolStudent` and you have tried to name your method `HighSchoolStudent` also. This is only allowed as the name of a constructor. For overriding `toString` you want to:

```
public class HighSchoolStudent extends Student
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return "high school student at "+super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess it does not want me to use @Override.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HighSchoolStudent extends Student
{
    public HighSchoolStudent(String schoolName)
    { 
        super(schoolName);
    }
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "high school " + super.toString();
    }
}
```